# Heat map and datetime axis. Value not displayed

Tags: highcharts

In a heat map with datetime axis.

If I do:

```
myData.push([column,row,1]);
```

It works, but If I change column for the ms it doesnt display anything in the cell.

```
myData.push([1407264705000,row,1]);
```

datetime:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
```

Comment: Do you have a complete JSFiddle example of when it doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623314/heat-map-with-time-line